# Is it possible to read network name in docker-compose from env?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm trying to not hard-code my network name since its for an open source project (and I have multiple instances running on the same server for different apps).

Is it possible to use environment variables when defining the network?

This doesn't work:

```
networks:
  ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}:
    name: ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compose has an internal notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) and most Docker object names are prefixed with that name.  For example, if you are in a directory named `foo` and your Compose file has

```yaml
networks:
  something:
```

and you run `docker network ls`, you will see a network named `foo_something`.

I would generally recommend not manually specifying the names of networks, volumes, or containers.  You can choose any name you want to be used within the `docker-compose.yml` file and it will be scoped to that file.

Conversely, this requires that different installations of the system either be in directories with different names, set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable (possibly in a `.env` file), or consistently use the `docker-compose -p` flag.

In the very specific case of networks, Compose [provides a network named `default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) which is the default if you don't actually have `networks:` blocks.  There's not really any downside to using this, and most applications won't need multiple internal networks.  I'd just leave out `networks:` entirely.